# How to mention the class path

Tags: java, classpath

How can I mention the path of a class as in following code?

```
Class cl=Class.forName("SomeClass");
```

This works well if the "SomeClass" is located in the same directory of the calling class. But how to check for a class from a different directory, I saw the syntax for that is like `xxxx.yyyy.class`, but could not make out what those 'x's and'y's stand for. please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [fully-qualified class name.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) For instance, to do this with the Java SE [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, which is in the `java.lang` package:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

Comment: my "SomeClass" is located at "E:\java\My Works\BankAccounts\src\bkac", bkac being the package name. now, how to call it in a class located at "E:\java\My Works\Inheritance\src"?

Comment: Is the class under `BankAccounts` in the classpath of the class under `Inheritance`?

Answer (score 1):

Those `xxx` and `yyy` stands for package names. Packages are normally represented by directories on disk with the same name as the package. When you create a class file you can specify which package the class goes by stating `package xxx.yyy` at the top of the file.

Referring to `"SomeClass"` without a package name will try to load a class named `SomeClass` in the default package.

Comment: my "SomeClass" is located at "E:\java\My Works\BankAccounts\src\bkac", bkac being the package name. now, how to call it in a class located at E:\java\My Works\Inheritance\src ?

Comment: The directory structure on disk does not really matter, it depends on if you've built jars or set the classpath appropriately. To make the BankAccounts stuff available from your other work you'd need to include it in the classpath so that the classloader knows that it can find classes in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Use Class.forName although make sure you deal with a possible ClassNotFoundException exception. This is a runtime exception so it does not mean you need to catch it. This is how you will know if you path to the class is correct. The problem is that if it cannot find the class funny things can happen with your code.

```
Class.forName(com.my.package.ClassName)
```